# Json.Net object passed to View in ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, json.net

I have a page in which I've implemented an ajax call to a controller that returns search results that are packaged in a JsonNetResult.

I have a lot of javascript to then deal with the return package, iterating over each item in the results set and outputting to the page.

Now, however, I need to implement the usage of these same methods for a single item that will be known on page load. I'd like to just pass this info to the View in a ViewData dictionary.

However, I don't know how to use Json.Net in this way.

How do I load a Json.Net object into a native json variable on page load, assuming that object has been stuffed into ViewData["DeepLinkedMessage"]?

I started to go down the path of this:

```
var thisMessage = (from userMessageProduct  .... more linq2sql stuff...);
bool success = (thisMessage.Count() == 0) ? false : true;
var returnPackage = new { success = success, results = thisMessage };
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
ViewData["DeepLinkedMessage"] = serializer.Serialize(returnPackage);
```

It worked just fine.  But I quickly noticed I'd have to solve the date formatting problems that I'd already solved when I set up the ajax call that returned JsonNetResult.  I want to use the exact same methods that I'm using now.

So, I started down this path:

```
JsonNetResult jsonNetResult = new JsonNetResult();
jsonNetResult.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());
jsonNetResult.Data = returnPackage;
ViewData["DeepLinkedMessage"] = jsonNetResult.ToString();
```

Then, in my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    deepLinkedMessageId = '<%=ViewData["DeepLinkMessageId"] %>';
    deepLinkedMessageRaw = '<%=ViewData["DeepLinkedMessage"]%>';
</script>
```

But this is returning this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    deepLinkedMessageId = '1';
    deepLinkedMessageRaw = 'WebUI.Controllers.JsonNetResult';
</script>
```

While I'm looking for something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    deepLinkedMessageId = '1';
    deepLinkedMessageRaw = '{"success":true,"results":[{"UserId":1,"InternalId":"1356935180","FirstName":"Scott","LastName":"Roberson","MessageId":1,"MessageText":"i just love your product!!!", "MessageCreateTime":"\/Date(1295289549930)\/","ProductId":5,"Flavor":"Almonds","ActivePixel":false,"ActiveClass":null,"TileNumber":0}]}';
</script>
```

Help using Json.Net for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found out from [here](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/20/good-date-times-with-json-net.aspx) that I can just do this:

```
bool success = (thisMessage.Count() == 0) ? false : true;
var returnPackage = new { success = success, results = thisMessage };
ViewData["DeepLinkedMessage"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnPackage, new IsoDateTimeConverter());
```

<wipes hands> "problem solved!"

Answer (score 0):

You should set your view to implement your model explicitely:

```
Inherits="System.Web.View<YourModelName>"
```

Then in your view you can do

```
Model.Property
```

I just find this easier to isolate where the problem is happening (plus viewdata can be a pain in the ass)

Comment: Well, the whole reason I'm putting it into the ViewData, instead of the Model, is because I'm already using the Inherits for the rest of the page  Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage <IEnumerable<DomainModel.ViewDataModels.HomePageUser>>"